# What is the minimal value of n such that the symmetric group Sn that contains an even permutation of order 312?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the minimal value of $n$  such that the symmetric group $S_n$ contains an even permutation of order 312?

what I know:
There is an 8-cycle, a 3-cycle and a 13-cycle.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So $n=8+3+13$ works. Why is it minimal? Same argument. Every permutation has a unique decomposition as a product of *disjoint* cycles, and we need at least one $8$-cycle, at least one $3$-cycle, and at least one $13$-cycle in this decomposition.

Comment: @dan_fulea plz make it an answer, so that i can upvote

Comment: @dan_fulea, is my answer n = 24 then? Thanks

Comment: I will write an answer, at a closer look, the permutation must be **even**...

Comment: @dan_fulea Yes so 8+3+13 is not even so what else can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Order of permutation is least common multiplier of lengths of it's cycles, and as permutation is even, it has even number of cycles of odd length. $n$ is sum of length of cycles, so we want to make this sum as small as possible.

Can we have cycle of length $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime numbers greater than $1$?  No - if we replace it with cycles of length $p$ and $q$, we don't change parity nor order of permutation, but reduce it's length - assume $p > q$ and write $p + q = p \cdot (1 + \frac{q}{p}) < p \cdot 2 \leq p \cdot q$. So lengths of all cycles should be powers of primes.

As $312 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13$, we need cycles of lengths $2^3$, $3$ and $13$. But we need an even number of cycles of even length, so we need at least one more cycle of even length. It can't have length less than $2$, so $n$ is at least $2^3 + 3 + 13 + 2$. And this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s$ be a permutation in a group $S_n$ having order $312=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 13$. We write it as a product of disjoint (thus commuting) cycles, let $N\ge 1$ be the number of cycles,
$$
s =c_1\cdot c_2\cdot c_3\cdot\; \dots \;\cdot c_N\ .
$$
Let $d_1, d_2,d_3,\dots,d_N$ be respectively the orders of these cycles.

Then the order of $s$ is the lcm of these orders.
Also, each order $d_j$ divides $312=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 13$.

---

As a digression, let us give some examples of realizations of permutations of order $312$. (Even or odd permutations so far.) Please skip this block with examples, if it feels annoying, and go directly to the restated **Problem**.

- For $n=312$ we have in $S_n$ the one cycle of order $312$, $c_1=(1,2,3,\dots,311,312)$, and take $s=c_1$, an odd permutation, there are $312-1=311$ inversions, $k<312$ "goes to" $k+1=s(k)>s(312)=1$.
- We may waste space and use $n=312+312$, and consider $s$ the product of the two cycles $c_1=(1,2,\dots,312)$ and $c_2=(312+1,312+2,\dots, 312+312)$. In such cases, i will denote the "second cycle" using a distinguishing character, e.g. $c_2=(1',2',\dots,312')$.
- For the representation $n=8+39$ we can take $c_1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ and $c_2=(1',2',\dots,39')$. This leads to an odd $s=c_1c_2$, since $c_1$ is odd, $c_2$ is even.
- To make the above example work, and deliver an even permutation, we may enlarge the space of $8+39$ symbols, and use $n=8+39+2$ symbols, where we can take $c_1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ and $c_2=(1',2',\dots,39')$ and $c_3=(1'',2'')$. Then the product of the three cycles is even, $c_1$ is odd, $c_2$ is even, the transposition $c_3$ is odd.
- For the representation $n=24+13$ we can take $c_1=(1,2,\dots,24)$ and $c_2=(1',2',\dots,13')$. This leads to an odd $s=c_1c_2$, since $c_1$ is odd, $c_2$ is even. As above, enlarge $n$ to the new value $n=24+13+2$ to produce an even permutation.
- For the representation $n=3+8+13$ we obtain again a solution by using
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  c_1 &= (1,2,3)\ ,\\
  c_2 &= (1',2',3',4',5',6',7',8')\ ,\\
  c_3 &= (1^*,2^*,3^*,4^*,5^*,6^*,7^*,8^*,9^*,10^*,11^*,12^*,13^*)\ ,\\
  s &=c_1c_2c_3\ ,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  but in this case the sign $(-1)^s$ (in my notation) of $s$ is
  $$
  (-1)^s=(-1)^{c_1}(-1)^{c_2}(-1)^{c_3}
  =(+1)(-1)(+1)=-1\ ,
  $$
  so this $s$ is odd.
- To have an even permutation of order $312$, with potential of being minimal, we can slightly adjust the above situation, by using $n=3+8+13+2$ and
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  c_1 &= (1,2,3)\ ,\\
  c_2 &= (1',2',3',4',5',6',7',8')\ ,\\
  c_3 &= (1^*,2^*,3^*,4^*,5^*,6^*,7^*,8^*,9^*,10^*,11^*,12^*,13^*)\ ,\\
  c_4 &= (1^a, 2^a)\ ,\\
  s &=c_1c_2c_3c_4\ ,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  and in this case the sign $(-1)^s$ of $s$ is
  $$
  (-1)^s=(-1)^{c_1}(-1)^{c_2}(-1)^{c_3}(-1)^{c_4}
  =(+1)(-1)(+1)(-1)=+1\ ,
  $$
  so this $s$ is a solution for the problem, disregarding the minimality.

Is this $s$ above minimal?

The orders $d_1,d_2,d_3,\dots,d_N$ of the cycles $c_1,c_2,c_3,\dots,c_N$ involved in $s$ already determine (up to isomorphism) the permutation $s$ and the minimal $n=\sum d=d_1+d_2+d_3+\dots+d_N$ needed to realize this cycle in $S_n$.

So the problem can be restated:

---

**Problem:** *Let $N\ge 1$ be a natural number, and let $d=(d_1,d_2,d_3,\dots,d_N)$ be a list of numbers $\ge 2$, with possible repetitions, all of them dividing $312=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 13$ such that:*

- *the lcm of these numbers is $312$.*
- *the number of the even entries in this list (those corresponding to odd cycles) is even*.
  *Which is the minimal value for $\sum d:= d_1+d_2+d_3+\dots+d_N$?*

---

We show that the minimal value is obtained for the list $(8,3,13,2)$.

Proof: Let $d$ be a possible list as above. The lcm of the entries in the list is $2^3\cdot 3\cdot 13$, so there exist indices $i,j,k$ with:

$8$ divides $d_i$, and $3$ divides $d_j$, and $13$ divides $d_k$.

- If $d_i>8$, then $d_i=8d_i'$ with an odd $d'$, and we replace the list $d$ by a list $D$, where we copy $d$, all entries but $d_i$, and instead of $d_i$ we use $d_i'$ in $D$, and introduce a new entry $d_{N+1}=8$ in $D$. The number of even entries in the list is the same. The lcm is the same. Observe now that:
  $$
  \sum D-\sum d = d_i'+8-8d_i'=8-7d_i'\le 8-7\cdot 2<0\ .
  $$
  So $D$ is "better". When searching for the minimal $d$, we can thus restrict and consider only lists $d$ with an entry equal to $8$, up to reordering let us assume $d_1=8$.
- The number of even entries in the list is even, so there is at least one further even entry, let this be $d_2$.
- The entries $d_j,d_k$ may "collide" with $d_1,d_2$, well only with $d_2$. (Since $d_1=8$ is not divisible by 3, also not by $13$.) Let's see if such collisions can lead to a minimal $\sum d$.
- If $j=2$, then $d_2$ is divisible by $2$, and by $3$. So $d_2\ge 6$. We replace then $d_2$ in $d$ by two entries, $2$ and $3$, obtain a new list $D$. The lcm is the same in $d$ and in $D$, the number of even entries is also the same. But $\sum D-\sum d=2+3-d_2\le 2+3-6<0$, so such a collision cannot deliver a minimal $d$.
- If $k=2$, then $d_2$ is divisible by $2$, and by $13$. Same argument. So $d_2\ge 26$. We replace then $d_2$ in $d$ by two entries, $2$ and $13$, obtain a new list $D$. The lcm is the same in $d$ and in $D$, the number of even entries is also the same. But $\sum D-\sum d=2+13-d_2\le 2+13-26<0$, so such a collision cannot deliver a minimal $d$.
- The collision $j=k$ is excluded similarly. We replace for instance $d_j$ in $d$ by two entries, $3$ and $d_j':=d_j/3$ (or $13$ and $d_j/13$) obtaining a new list $D$, and
  $\sum D-\sum d=3+d_j'-3d_j'=3-2d_j'\le 3\cdot 2\cdot 2<0$, so the minimal $\sum d$ does not occur in case of such a collision.
- After all these exclusions, the indices $1,2,j,k$ differ when realizing a minimal $\sum d$, which implies:
  $$
  \sum d\ge d_1+d_2+d_j+d_k\ge 8+2+3+13=26\ .
  $$
  $\square$